# Slow joomla site from time to time

Tags: performance, joomla, loading, server

The joomla 2.5 site (shared hosting) http://dppumps.eu/home (temporary homepage) from time to time is extremely slow. When visiting after a long time it may take up to 30sec to load, and it has happened to me several times to get 500 internal server error after loading for a long time. When refreshed it takes from 0.5 sec to 4 sec to load. How is it possible to have such a big range in loading time? Maybe a server issue or something in my script? Thank you. (I have created numerous sites with joomla 2.5 hosted in the same hosting company with no problems)

Comment: Did you check your server's logs to see what's up with the 500? Plus this isn't really programming. it's more server administration. Especially since you've provided NO useful details, like actual code or configuration.

Comment: In the error log I found only this: File does not exist: /home/dppumpse/public_html/500.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You really do need to do some research before you ask questions like this.

First thing you should always do is run a site speed test using [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) or something similar. I've run a test on your and you're initially loading **11.1MB** of data.

**6.6MB** of this data is from 2 flash video files which cannot even be found. You then have to take into consideration that you've most likely not used web compression when saving images for your website.

In addition to this, you may want to consider enabling Joomla's GZip compression in the Global Configuration **and** enable the System Cache plugin. Should you not want to do this, I would strongly suggest using a caching plugin such as [JCH Optimize](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/jch-optimize).

Article upon article has been written regarding slow website so please look around to see what methods suits you the most

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have tested the site using pingdom. The first "not found" file is flashmediaelement.swf (0kb) is a native file in widgetkit, not added by me, and the other one video.flv it exists. I don't know why it is listed. I have disabled the background slideshow with all the heavy graphics and the data loading is now 1.8MB! And yet according to pingdom the loading time differs from 1sec to 10 sec! What I want to say is that the page is not always slow, I have measured very different loading times, that's why I thought about a server issue. Again thanks for helping!